# Update Container to new size

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have custom control inside TabPanel: {items: Panel: {items: customcontrol}}. 
Inside control, i create dynamically in onRender handler image control with picture. Picture can be different sizes. How me refresh current container, that it took the right size? It happen automatically, then i switch to another tab and back. doLayout() not working, function updateLayout() violates the layout of the other tabs.

creating image:

```
    onRender: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);
        this.el.update(this.imageFieldTpl.apply(this));
        var imageWrap = Ext.query('.image-ct', this.el.dom)[0];

        this['image'] = Ext.create(Ext.Img, {      
            name: 'image',
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            renderTo: imageWrap
        });
        if (this.value != null) {
            this.fireEvent('imageChange', this.value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Direct rendering of a component into another component's element is too rough and primitive approach to satisfy your requirements. `Ext.Img` (or maybe even a custom class derived from it) should be a descendant component of your Panel rather than rendered into it the way you are doing.

Comment: Controls is not Panel, cause i have requrement that control must be descendant of field, in this case:  extend: 'Ext.form.Field'. I hope doing that do activating tab, image have right size on toggling tabs. But i not understanding how it work. using this.ownerCt.ownerCt.ownerCt.setActiveTab working incorrect.

Comment: Also i try collapse\expand panel, but panel collapsing and not expanding back.

Comment: OK extend your controls from `Ext.form.Field` then. The point is to stick to Ext JS way of extending / nesting components so that all resizing job can be left up to the layout engine.